# Select multiple files from a FileUploadField in extjs

Tags: extjs3

I'm looking at the example [here](http://ngs.woc.noaa.gov/storms/scripts/ext-3.2.1/examples/form/file-upload.html) and using the javascript provided from that example [here](http://ngs.woc.noaa.gov/storms/scripts/ext-3.2.1/examples/ux/fileuploadfield/FileUploadField.js).  Basically what I want is a stand alone file chooser where I can select as many files as I want.  The example that I've tried has a stand alone upload button but they don't let me shift highlight multiple files at the same time.

This code creates the button, but I can't load in multiple files at the same time:

```
var addFilesButton = new Ext.ux.form.FileUploadField({
    buttonText: 'Add Files...',
    buttonOnly: true,
    listeners: {
        'fileselected': function(fb, v){
          var Record = myGrid.getStore().recordType;
          var newFile = new Record({
            fileName:       v,
            type:           'src',
            version:        '5.9',
          });

          myGrid.stopEditing();
          myGrid.getStore().add(newFile);
          myGrid.startEditing(0, 0);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ext.ux.form.FileUpload` uses *HTML INPUT* field to set a file to upload which is pretty normal thing to do.

If you are using HTML4, at most one file can be assigned to input file field.

However, from *HTML5*, there is [a special attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#file-upload-state-%28type=file%29) that you can set to accept multiple files.

I have [modified the script](https://gist.github.com/calvin/6075843) accordingly and created [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bjM8K/).

Note that HTML5 spec is still in draft. [Feature compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=forms) is available on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=forms)

Comment: Thank you for the very in depth answer.  unfortunatly I'm not using html 5 but I have tried the example here: http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2012/03/extjs-3-enabling-multiple-file-uploads-using-textfield and I'm able to do multiple uploads with his code.  The problem with his code is that it has a text box in it and for some reason I can't remove the text box.  Any more ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @Grammin the example that you provided also uses the `multiple` attribute.

Comment: I retried everything and this time got it to work... Thank you very much for you help I wish I could give you more then one upvote.

Answer (score 1):

My MultiFileUploadField class:

```
MultiFileUploadField = Ext.extend(Ext.ux.form.FileUploadField, {
  multiple: false,

  createFileInput: function() {
    this.fileInput = this.wrap.createChild({
      id: this.getFileInputId(),
      name: this.name||this.getId(),
      cls: 'x-form-file',
      tag: 'input',
      type: 'file',
      size: 1
    }); 

    if(this.multiple){
      this.fileInput.dom.setAttribute('multiple', 'multiple');
    }   
  },  

 bindListeners: function(){
   this.fileInput.on({
     scope: this,
     mouseenter: function(){
       this.button.addClass(['x-btn-over','x-btn-focus'])
     },  
     mouseleave: function(){
       this.button.removeClass(['x-btn-over','x-btn-focus','x-btn-click'])
     },  
     mousedown: function(){
       this.button.addClass('x-btn-click')
     },  
     mouseup: function(){
       this.button.removeClass(['x-btn-over','x-btn-focus','x-btn-click'])
     },  
     change: function(){
       var v = this.fileInput.dom.files;
       this.setValue(v);
       this.fireEvent('fileselected', this, v); 
     }   
   }); 
  },  
});
```